# How to deliver the class of a generic type to a method in Java?

Tags: java

I want to implement a class that instantiates generic types.

```
public class DisjointSet<T extends Set<E>, E> {

    private final Class<T> setType;

    public DisjointSet(Class<T> setClass) {
        this.setType = setClass;
    }

    public void doSomething(E Element) {
        T set = setClass.newInstance();
        set.add(element);
    }
}
```

I tried instantiating the class like this:

```
DisjointSet<HashSet<Integer>, Integer> disjointSet = new DisjointSet<>(HashSet<Integer>.class);
```

However using `.class` on a generic type does not seem to be allowed. How would I correctly pass the required Class of a generic type to the constructor?

Comment: I would suggest you look into the way the Jackson library handles this problem: it has its own generic class, TypeReference, that is used as a proxy for the class.  I haven't looked into how it's implemented, but it seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it is good to expose the inner set type (Hash versus other) in the parameterized type.
Actually due to type erasure you can't instantiate parameterised types directly, but you can pass in a factory,

```
package langGenerics;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UseGenerics {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SetFactory<Integer> setFactory = HashSet::new;
    DisjointSet<Integer> disjointSet = new DisjointSet<>(setFactory);
    disjointSet.doSomething( 123 );
  }
}

interface SetFactory<T> { Set<T> get(); }

class DisjointSet<T> {
  private SetFactory<T> setFactory;
  public DisjointSet(SetFactory<T> setFactory) {
    this.setFactory = setFactory;
  }
  public void doSomething(T item) {
      Set<T> set = setFactory.get();
      set.add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I need. The visible inner set type is against my own liking, but appears to be a necessity for the project that I'm involved in, since the sets are going to be used outside the class and extended with a few helpful methods.
The only alternative seemed to be designing the DisjointSet for just one specific purpose, which was even less agreeable for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to init your own set storage, then I suggest you to pass `Supplier` to your constructor:

```
public static class DisjointSet<T extends Set<E>, E> {
    T set;
    public DisjointSet(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        set = supplier.get();
    }

    public void doSomething(E element) {
        set.add(element);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
DisjointSet<HashSet<Integer>, Integer> set = new DisjointSet<>(HashSet::new);
```

Comment: If you do it this way, you can't have any operations in the class that work on the elements of the set, because there's no way of declaring the element type.

Answer (score 0):

if this is what you wanted,

```
public class DisjointSet<T extends Set<E>, E> {

    private final Class<T> setType;

    public DisjointSet(Class<T> setClass) {
        this.setType = setClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisjointSet<HashSet<Integer>, Integer> disjointSet = new DisjointSet(new HashSet<Integer>().getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that e.g. `HashSet.class` isn't a valid type to call the constructor with, and `HashSet<String>.class` isn't legal syntax.